# Using Shared Memory in Cuda

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, cuda

I got this function in Cuda ( C ):

```
__global__ void FUN1(float *data,int M){

    int I=blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int J=blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;int k;
    int index=I+J*M;

    if((J<N)&&(I<N)){
        Arr2[index]=Arr1[index];
        for(k=0;k<M;k++){
            if(Arr2[index]>(Arr2[I+M*k] + Arr2[k+M*J])){
                Arr2[index]=Arr2[I+M*k] + Arr2[k+M*J];
            }   
        }
    }   
}
```

Calling from main , for some big integer, M , and given an array (2d in flat version ) data[ M ] 
like this:

```
FUN1<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(Array1,M);
```

Grid is rectangular.

My function reacts good, implementing the APSP (ALL SHORTEST PATH)problem . However ,when i try to implement this with shared memory i got stacked and get half of my results as i expected,and the other half garbage.

This is my try for using shared memory :

```
__global__ void fmDistC(float *Arr1,float *Arr2,int N){

    unsigned int k,m;int bx=blockIdx.x;int by=blockIdx.y;
    int tx=threadIdx.y;int ty=threadIdx.y;

    int I=bx*blockDim.x + tx;
    int J=by*blockDim.y + ty;   
    int index=J+I*N;

    __shared__ float sArr[2*BLOCKSIZE]; 

    if((I<N)&&(J<N)){
        float con=0.0f;
        for(m=0;m<(gridDim.y);m++){
            Arr2[index]=Arr1[index];
            sArr[tx+ty]=Arr2[I*N+(m*by)+ty];
            sArr[tx+ty]=Arr2[J+N*(m*bx+tx)];
            __syncthreads();

            for(k=0;k<bx;k++){  
                if(Arr2[index]>(sArr[k+tx]+sArr[ty+k]))
                    con=sArr[k+tx]+sArr[ty+k];
                    __syncthreads();
            }
        }
        Arr2[index]=con;
    }
}
```

Can someone give me a direction on how can i go to the "right" way?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The shared memory code you've provided won't compile, so its not what you are running.  Your `index` calculation almost certainly exceeds `BLOCKSIZE`, so you would immediately be indexing out-of-bounds as you try to load shared memory at `sdata[index]=...`.  Questions asking for debugging help should provide a [mcve].

Comment: @RobertCrovella you are right.I just edit my code.With the one i just work right now.Its full compilable.I suspect that somethings is goings wrong in part sArr[tx+ty]=Arr [....]

Comment: CUDA is **not** [tag:C]!

Comment: @AndreasPapadopoulos: "C and C++ are different languages" - Do tell! There is no CUDA-C, CUDA is C++ based. Does `FUN1<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(Array1,M);` look like valid C? Using C for CUDA is exactly the same missconception for adding C tag to C++ question: They **think** they are the same language.

Answer (score 1):

On this line
`int tx=threadIdx.y;int ty=threadIdx.y;`

You are setting your tx variable to threadIdx.y instead of threadIdx.x

This could explain problems with indexing.